# Regular Expression for not allowing two consecutive special characters and also not in beginning and end

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a regex for a string to

1. Contain only A-Z a-z 0-9 _ - .
2. Not begin/end with _ - .
3. Not containing consecutive special characters or their combination
4. Max 36 length, minimum 1

**Right**

```
abcd-efgH
1
a
123
abc
abc-asd-123-asd_asd.asd
```

**Wrong:**

```
-
abc-_asd
abc.
abc.-asd
123123-123123-ads--asd
091-asdsad---
```

I seearched around and got this :-

```
/^(?!.*[^\na-z0-9]{2})(?=.*[a-z0-9]$)[a-z0-9].*$/gim
```

but this allows all special characters and not just the 3 that i checek

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this regex with 3 lookaheads:

```
^(?![-_.])(?!.*[-_.]{2})(?!.*[-_.]$)[-\w.]{1,36}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zl0XtA/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?![-_.])`: Negative lookahead to disallow `[-_.]` at the start
- `(?!.*[-_.]{2})`: Negative lookahead to disallow 2 consecutive `[-_.]` anywhere
- `(?!.*[-_.]$)`: Negative lookahead to disallow `[-_.]` at the end
- `[-\w.]{1,36}`: Match a `[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]` character, min: 1, max: 36
- `$`: End

Comment: ...or `^(?!.*[-_.]{2})(?!.*[-_.]$)[^-_.][-\w.]{0,35}$`.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland but that will also match `$abc` where `$` is not an allowed character. But `^(?!.*[-_.]{2})(?!.*[-_.]$)[a-zA-Z0-9][-\w.]{0,35}$` should  work fine.

Comment: After having my morning coffee I'm slapping my head (lightly). Yesterday I was informed that in Java, unlike most languages, regular expressions must match the entire string. Does that mean that in this case you don't need the anchors?

Comment: anchors are not needed only when regex is being used in `matches` method

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
/^(?!.{37,})[a-z\d]+(?:[-._][a-z\d]+)*$/gim
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/10bmbN/6)

---

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `(?!.{37,})` - Negative lookahead for 37 characters or more.
- `[a-z\d]+` - At least a single character within this character group.
- `(?:` - Open non-capturing group.

  - `[-._]` - A single character within this character group.
  - `[a-z\d]+` - At least a single character within this character group.
  - `)*` - Close non-capturing group and match it zero or more times.
- `$` - End string ancor.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest and most direct way to solve this problem, in an intuitive and logical way, is the following:

```
/^([a-z\d]|(?<![-_])(?<!^)[-_](?!$)){2,36}$/gim
```

The explanation is pretty simple.

The first char can be letter or digit `OR` (|) the first character can be  additionally be `_` or `-`, since the previous char

**a)** is not `_` neither `-`.

The previous char condition is in the [negative  lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(?<![-_])`

It means, using the current cursor position, a negative look behind  (represented by `(?<! P)` model, where `P` is a pattern) and it's ok just if pattern `P` don't (`negative`) fit (PS: Lookbehind don't move the cursor)
In this case, pattern `P` is just `[-_]`. If `P` behind is not `-` neither `_`, it means that `-` or `_` are allowed as a option!

**b)** `_` ou `-` is not in the start

Right after that we have another negative look behind that tests only the beginning of the text. P is just ^(the anchor that indicates start of the text). The look behind piece is `(?<!^)` (`P` is just `^`)

**c)**  `_` ou `-`  is not in the end

Finally  we have a negative look forward, but is appears after [-_] real pattern. The only syntax difference is cut "<" character (`?!P`, where `P` is the pattern). Now, the regex processing is search forward for the pattern P, without move the cursor. If the pattern fail is OK (negative!)
In the case, we have `(?!$)`, where `P` is `$`, the anchor that indicates the end of the text.

for example:
`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU-XYZ01234_56789` matches
but `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU-_XYZ0123456789` doesn't match
neither `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU-XYZ012345678_`
neither `_BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU-XYZ0123456789`

See online [here](https://regex101.com/r/wzeqiG/4):